# Automated test for a async Command in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, mvvm, integration-testing

I have an asynchronous `Command` class, like so:

```
public AsyncDelegateCommand(Func<Task> execute, Func<bool> canExecute)
{
    this.execute = execute;
    this.canExecute = canExecute;
}

public virtual bool CanExecute(object parameter)
{
    if(executing)
        return false;
    if(canExecute == null)
        return true;
    return canExecute();
}

public async void Execute(object parameter) // Notice "async void"
{
    executing = true;
    CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
    if(parameter != null && executeWithParameter != null)
        await executeWithParameter(parameter);
    else if(execute != null)
        await execute();
    executing = false;
    CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
}
```

And it is called like so:

```
FindProductCommand = new AsyncDelegateCommand(TryToFindProduct, () => CanFindProduct() && connector.HasConnection);

private async Task TryToFindProduct()
{
    //code
}
```

When I unit tests, it works just fine, since I'm returning instantly from tasks.

However, when writing my integration test, I run into trouble. I am not able to await `Execute`, since it is `void`, and I am not able to change it to `Task`. I end up doing this: :/

```
findProductViewModel.FindProductCommand.Execute(null);
Thread.Sleep(2000);

var informationViewModel = findProductViewModel.ProductViewModel.ProductInformationViewModel;

Assert.AreEqual("AFG00", informationViewModel.ProductGroup);
```

**Is there a better solution for this test?** Maybe something that is reliant on how long it actually takes, and doesn't estimate how long to wait.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer to a good blog post by @StephenCleary: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn630647.aspx
`async void` is generally to be avoided, so he introduces a new interface (and its base implementation) for an async command: `IAsyncCommand`. This interface contains a method `async Task ExecuteAsync(object parameter)` that you could await in your tests.

```
public interface IAsyncCommand : ICommand
{
  Task ExecuteAsync(object parameter);
}

public abstract class AsyncCommandBase : IAsyncCommand
{
  public abstract bool CanExecute(object parameter);
  public abstract Task ExecuteAsync(object parameter);

  public async void Execute(object parameter)
  {
    await ExecuteAsync(parameter);
  }

  public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
  {
    add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
    remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
  }

  protected void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
  {
    CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
  }
}
```

The simplest implementation of such an async command would look like this:

```
public class AsyncCommand : AsyncCommandBase
{
  private readonly Func<Task> _command;

  public AsyncCommand(Func<Task> command)
  {
    _command = command;
  }

  public override bool CanExecute(object parameter)
  {
    return true;
  }

  public override Task ExecuteAsync(object parameter)
  {
    return _command();
  }
}
```

But there are more advanced variants that you can find in the linked blog post. You can use the `IAsyncCommand`s in your code all the way, so you can test them. The MVVM framework you use will also be happy, because that interface is based on the `ICommand`.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a better solution for this test? Maybe something that is reliant on how long it actually takes, and doesn't estimate how long to wait.

Certainly: Make the command awaitable and `await` it. `async` `void` methods are bad practice and are *only* meant to be used for event handlers.

There are awaitable commands available in [Mvvm.Async](https://github.com/StephenCleary/Mvvm.Async/blob/master/src/Nito.Mvvm.Async/AsyncCommand.cs) and [ReactiveUI](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/b5d1d263673df519b9027a9f67eab26d6653c7a7/src/ReactiveUI/ReactiveCommand.cs) that you can use or at least take a look at for reference.

Comment: Thank you. It appears your link points me towards StephanCleary. This is the same as @dymanoid suggested. Since he provided and example I'll give him the accepted answer, but have an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a state to check for, you should probably just use [SpinWait.SpinUntil](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449238(v=vs.110).aspx):

It will be much more reliable than `Thread.Sleep`as it allows you to check if a condition is true before continuing.

e.g.

```
findProductViewModel.FindProductCommand.Execute(null);
SpinWait.SpinUntil(() => findProductViewModel.ProductViewModel.ProductInformationViewModel != null, 5000);

var informationViewModel = findProductViewModel.ProductViewModel.ProductInformationViewModel;

Assert.AreEqual("AFG00", informationViewModel.ProductGroup);
```

Comment: Very useful. I might take that into consideration next time I am unable to await execution. I have been shown awaiting can be made possible though. Thank you.