# Why my async command invocation unit test does not work?

Tags: c#, command, task, moq, xunit

Ok, I am trying to figure it out a few hours already, so I decided to as a question here.

I am using **xUnit** and **Moq** frameworks.

Few words about my SUT. I have an async command:

```
public IAsyncCommand SimulateResultsCommand { get; private set; }
```

And the command calls a method:

```
SimulateResultsCommand = new AsyncCommand(async () => await OnSimulateResultsExecuteAsync());
```

Method is calling service layer method:

```
public async Task OnSimulateResultsExecuteAsync()
{
    //init controls here

    Races = await _simulateDataService.SimulateResultsAsync(It.IsAny<int>(), Races.Count, Races, Horses, Jockeys, RaceModelProvider);

    //reset controls here
}
```

For creating async command I refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45878669/11027921). The problem is, that when I am testing it, the test is failing with a message:

> Message: Moq.MockException :  Expected invocation on the mock once,
>   but was 0 times: sd => sd.SimulateResultsAsync(It.IsAny(), 0, [], [], [],
>   RaceModel)
>
> Performed invocations:
>
> Mock (sd):
>
> ISimulateService.SimulateResultsAsync(0, 0, [], [], [], RaceModel)

And the test looks like this:

```
[Fact]
public async Task OnSimulateResultsExecuteAsync_CallsSimulateResultsAsync()
{
    List<RaceDetails> races = new List<RaceDetails>();
    List<LoadedHorse> horses = new List<LoadedHorse>();
    List<LoadedJockey> jockeys = new List<LoadedJockey>();
    RaceModel race = new RaceModel();

    await _viewModel.SimulateResultsCommand.ExecuteAsync(null);

    _simulateDataMock.Verify(sd => sd.SimulateResultsAsync(0, races.Count, races, horses, jockeys, race), Times.Once);
}
```

Mock injection:

```
private MainViewModel _viewModel;
private Mock<ISimulateService> _simulateDataMock;

public MainViewModelTests()
{
    _simulateDataMock = new Mock<ISimulateService>();

    _viewModel = new MainViewModel(_simulateDataMock.Object);
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Why there is no **invocation on the mock**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should match the arguments by *any* value using `It.IsAny<T>()`:

```
_simulateDataMock.Verify(sd => sd.SimulateResultsAsync(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<int>(),
    It.IsAny<List<RaceDetails>>(), It.IsAny<List<LoadedHorse>>(), It.IsAny<List<LoadedJockey>>(),
    It.IsAny<RaceModel>()), Times.Once);
```

Comment: This solution worked, you are great, **mm8**, as usual. I am just wondering now, why `sd => sd.SimulateResultsAsync(It.IsAny(), 0, [], [], [], RaceModel)` did not match with `ISimulateService.SimulateResultsAsync(0, 0, [], [], [], RaceModel)` in the test, as per exception message?

Comment: @bakunet: Basically because your test expects the method to be called with the local instances that you create in the unit test, but the view model calls it with other instances.

Comment: Ok, I get it now. If they are two different instances not referring to the same object, they will fail in **Equals** comparison. I belive that framework uses this. Tahnk you.